# In spark, is their any alternative for union() function while appending new row?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my code `table_df` has some columns on which I am doing some calculations like min, max, mean etc. and I want to create new_df with specified schema new_df_schema. In my logic, I have written spark-sql for calculations and appending each new generated row to initially empty new_df and at the end, it results in `new_df` with all calculated values for all columns.

But the problem is when the columns are more in number it leads to performance issue. Can this be done without using union() function or any other approach to increase performance?

```py
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

    val table_df = Seq(
      (10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
      (100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
      (111, 222, 333, 444, 555),
      (1123, 2123, 3123, 4123, 5123),
      (1321, 2321, 3321, 4321, 5321)
    ).toDF("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", "col_5")
    table_df.show(false)

    table_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_df")

     val new_df_schema = StructType(
      StructField("Column_Name", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("number_of_values", LongType, false) ::
        StructField("number_of_distinct_values", LongType, false) ::
        StructField("distinct_count_with_nan", LongType, false) ::
        StructField("distinct_count_without_nan", LongType, false) ::
        StructField("is_unique", BooleanType, false) ::
        StructField("number_of_missing_values", LongType, false) ::
        StructField("percentage_of_missing_values", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("percentage_of_unique_values", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("05_PCT", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("25_PCT", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("50_PCT", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("75_PCT", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("95_PCT", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("max", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("min", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("mean", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("std", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("skewness", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("kurtosis", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("range", DoubleType, false) ::
        StructField("variance", DoubleType, false) :: Nil
    )
    var new_df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], new_df_schema)

    for (c <- table_df.columns) {
      val num = sparkSession.sql(
        s"""SELECT
           | '$c' AS Column_Name,
           | COUNT(${c}) AS number_of_values,
           | COUNT(DISTINCT ${c}) AS number_of_distinct_values,
           | COUNT(DISTINCT ${c}) AS distinct_count_with_nan,
           | (COUNT(DISTINCT ${c}) - 1) AS distinct_count_without_nan,
           | (COUNT(${c}) == COUNT(DISTINCT ${c})) AS is_unique,
           | (COUNT(*) - COUNT(${c})) AS number_of_missing_values,
           | ((COUNT(*) - COUNT(${c}))/COUNT(*)) AS percentage_of_missing_values,
           | (COUNT(DISTINCT ${c})/COUNT(*)) AS percentage_of_unique_values,
           | APPROX_PERCENTILE($c,0.05) AS 05_PCT,
           | APPROX_PERCENTILE($c,0.25) AS 25_PCT,
           | APPROX_PERCENTILE($c,0.50) AS 50_PCT,
           | APPROX_PERCENTILE($c,0.75) AS 75_PCT,
           | APPROX_PERCENTILE($c,0.95) AS 95_PCT,
           | MAX($c) AS max,
           | MIN($c) AS min,
           | MEAN($c) AS mean,
           | STD($c) AS std,
           | SKEWNESS($c) AS skewness,
           | KURTOSIS($c) AS kurtosis,
           | (MAX($c) - MIN($c)) AS range,
           | VARIANCE($c) AS variance
           | FROM
           | table_df""".stripMargin)
        .toDF()
      new_df = new_df.union(num) // this results performance issue when then number of columns in table_df is more
    }
    new_df.show(false)

==================================================
table_df:
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|10   |20   |30   |40   |50   |
|100  |200  |300  |400  |500  |
|111  |222  |333  |444  |555  |
|1123 |2123 |3123 |4123 |5123 |
|1321 |2321 |3321 |4321 |5321 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

new_df:

+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+-----------------+
|Column_Name|number_of_values|number_of_distinct_values|distinct_count_with_nan|distinct_count_without_nan|is_unique|number_of_missing_values|percentage_of_missing_values|percentage_of_unique_values|05_PCT|25_PCT|50_PCT|75_PCT|95_PCT|max   |min |mean  |std               |skewness           |kurtosis           |range |variance         |
+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+-----------------+
|col_1      |5               |5                        |5                      |4                         |true     |0                       |0.0                         |1.0                        |10.0  |100.0 |111.0 |1123.0|1321.0|1321.0|10.0|533.0 |634.0634826261484 |0.4334269738367067 |-1.7463346405299973|1311.0|402036.5         |
|col_2      |5               |5                        |5                      |4                         |true     |0                       |0.0                         |1.0                        |20.0  |200.0 |222.0 |2123.0|2321.0|2321.0|20.0|977.2 |1141.1895986206673|0.4050513738738682 |-1.799741951675132 |2301.0|1302313.7        |
|col_3      |5               |5                        |5                      |4                         |true     |0                       |0.0                         |1.0                        |30.0  |300.0 |333.0 |3123.0|3321.0|3321.0|30.0|1421.4|1649.399072389699 |0.3979251063785061 |-1.8119558312496054|3291.0|2720517.3        |
|col_4      |5               |5                        |5                      |4                         |true     |0                       |0.0                         |1.0                        |40.0  |400.0 |444.0 |4123.0|4321.0|4321.0|40.0|1865.6|2157.926620624529 |0.39502047381456235|-1.8165124206347685|4281.0|4656647.3        |
|col_5      |5               |5                        |5                      |4                         |true     |0                       |0.0                         |1.0                        |50.0  |500.0 |555.0 |5123.0|5321.0|5321.0|50.0|2309.8|2666.59027598917  |0.3935246673563026 |-1.8186685628112493|5271.0|7110703.699999999|
+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to get exact new_df output. have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to `union`.

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|10   |20   |30   |40   |50   |
|100  |200  |300  |400  |500  |
|111  |222  |333  |444  |555  |
|1123 |2123 |3123 |4123 |5123 |
|1321 |2321 |3321 |4321 |5321 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Build Required Expressions.

```
scala> val descExpr = array(
    df.columns
    .map(c => struct(
        lit(c).cast("string").as("column_name"),
        max(col(c)).cast("string").as("max"),
        min(col(c)).cast("string").as("min"),
        mean(col(c)).cast("string").as("mean"),
        stddev(col(c)).cast("string").as("std"),
        skewness(col(c)).cast("string").as("skewness"),
        kurtosis(col(c)).cast("string").as("kurtosis")
        )
    ):_*
).as("data")
```

Required Columns.

````py
val columns = Seq("column_name","max","min","mean","std","skewness","kurtosis")
 .map(c => if(c != "column_name") col(c).cast("double").as(c) else col(c))```
````

**Final Output**

```
scala> df
 .select(descExpr)
 .selectExpr("explode(data) as data")
 .select("data.*")
 .select(columns:_*)
 .show(false)

+-----------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|column_name|max   |min |mean  |std               |skewness           |kurtosis           |
+-----------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|col_1      |1321.0|10.0|533.0 |634.0634826261484 |0.43342697383670664|-1.7463346405299978|
|col_2      |2321.0|20.0|977.2 |1141.1895986206673|0.4050513738738679 |-1.7997419516751327|
|col_3      |3321.0|30.0|1421.4|1649.3990723896993|0.397925106378506  |-1.8119558312496056|
|col_4      |4321.0|40.0|1865.6|2157.9266206245293|0.3950204738145622 |-1.8165124206347691|
|col_5      |5321.0|50.0|2309.8|2666.5902759891706|0.3935246673563026 |-1.81866856281125  |
+-----------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**Updated**

```
scala> val finalDF = df.select(descExpr).selectExpr("explode(data) as data").select("data.*").select(columns:_*)
```

Create new dataframe with `Approx Quantile` for all columns.

```
scala> val approxQuantileDF = df
.columns
.map(c => (c,df.stat.approxQuantile(c,Array(0.25,0.5,0.75),0.0)))
.toList
.toDF("column_name","approx_quantile")
```

```
scala> finalDF
        .join(approxQuantileDF,
              Seq("column_name"),
              "left"
    ).show(false)
+-----------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------+
|column_name|max   |min |mean  |std               |skewness           |kurtosis           |approx_quantile       |
+-----------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------+
|col_1      |1321.0|10.0|533.0 |634.0634826261484 |0.43342697383670664|-1.7463346405299978|[100.0, 111.0, 1123.0]|
|col_2      |2321.0|20.0|977.2 |1141.1895986206673|0.4050513738738679 |-1.7997419516751327|[200.0, 222.0, 2123.0]|
|col_3      |3321.0|30.0|1421.4|1649.3990723896993|0.397925106378506  |-1.8119558312496056|[300.0, 333.0, 3123.0]|
|col_4      |4321.0|40.0|1865.6|2157.9266206245293|0.3950204738145622 |-1.8165124206347691|[400.0, 444.0, 4123.0]|
|col_5      |5321.0|50.0|2309.8|2666.5902759891706|0.3935246673563026 |-1.81866856281125  |[500.0, 555.0, 5123.0]|
+-----------+------+----+------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Is there someway to add percentile analysis with these operations without using UDF or hive?
like:
DF.stat.approxQuantile("<Col_Name>",Array(0.25,0.5,0.75),0.0)
but with one column at a time and then also creating new columns for each percentile

Comment: Check now I have added that also. Please accept this solution if it helps.

Comment: I have started bounty, see if you can answer :)

Comment: @Srinivas when i do " percentile(col(c),0.0).cast("string").as("percentile_0")," its giving error as " error: not found: value percentile" why it is not able to found it ?

Comment: @Srinivas  tried this too "df.stat.percentile(col(c),0.0).cast("string").as("percentile_0"),"" giving error as "" error: value percentile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions ""

Comment: @vishalraj, you accepted solution & gave bounty to different person .. :)

Comment: @BdEngineer, I will check that & will update you in that question.

Comment: @Srinivas, thanks a lot , i have another use case like this , any advice please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137437/doing-multiple-column-value-look-up-after-joining-with-lookup-dataset

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative -
there is a **`summary()`** api inside dataset which computes basicStats in the below format-

```scala
    ds.summary("count", "min", "25%", "75%", "max").show()
   
    // output:
    // summary age   height
    // count   10.0  10.0
    // min     18.0  163.0
    // 25%     24.0  176.0
    // 75%     32.0  180.0
    // max     92.0  192.0
```

Similarly, You can enrich the dataframe apis to get the stats in the format you required as below-

### Define `RichDataframe` & `implicits` to use

```scala
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{NumericType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

import scala.language.implicitConversions

class RichDataFrame(ds: DataFrame) {
  def statSummary(statistics: String*): DataFrame = {
    val defaultStatistics = Seq("max", "min", "mean", "std", "skewness", "kurtosis")
    val statFunctions = if (statistics.nonEmpty) statistics else defaultStatistics
    val selectedCols = ds.schema
      .filter(a => a.dataType.isInstanceOf[NumericType] || a.dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType])
      .map(_.name)

    val percentiles = statFunctions.filter(a => a.endsWith("%")).map { p =>
      try {
        p.stripSuffix("%").toDouble / 100.0
      } catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException =>
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unable to parse $p as a percentile", e)
      }
    }
    require(percentiles.forall(p => p >= 0 && p <= 1), "Percentiles must be in the range [0, 1]")
    val aggExprs = selectedCols.flatMap(c => {
      var percentileIndex = 0
      statFunctions.map { stats =>
        if (stats.endsWith("%")) {
          val index = percentileIndex
          percentileIndex += 1
          expr(s"cast(percentile_approx($c, array(${percentiles.mkString(", ")}))[$index] as string)")
        } else {
          expr(s"cast($stats($c) as string)")
        }
      }
    })

    val aggResult = ds.select(aggExprs: _*).head()

    val r = aggResult.toSeq.grouped(statFunctions.length).toArray
      .zip(selectedCols)
      .map{case(seq, column) => column +: seq }
      .map(Row.fromSeq)

    val output = StructField("columns", StringType) +: statFunctions.map(c => StructField(c, StringType))

    val spark = ds.sparkSession
    spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(r), StructType(output))
  }
}

object RichDataFrame {

  trait Enrichment {
    implicit def enrichMetadata(ds: DataFrame): RichDataFrame =
      new RichDataFrame(ds)
  }

  object implicits extends Enrichment

}
```

### Test with the provided test data as below

```scala
     val table_df = Seq(
      (10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
      (100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
      (111, 222, 333, 444, 555),
      (1123, 2123, 3123, 4123, 5123),
      (1321, 2321, 3321, 4321, 5321)
    ).toDF("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", "col_5")
    table_df.show(false)
    table_df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      * |col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|
      * +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      * |10   |20   |30   |40   |50   |
      * |100  |200  |300  |400  |500  |
      * |111  |222  |333  |444  |555  |
      * |1123 |2123 |3123 |4123 |5123 |
      * |1321 |2321 |3321 |4321 |5321 |
      * +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- col_1: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- col_2: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- col_3: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- col_4: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- col_5: integer (nullable = false)
      */


    import RichDataframe.implicits._
    table_df.statSummary()
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+----+---+------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
      * |columns|max |min|mean  |std               |skewness          |kurtosis           |
      * +-------+----+---+------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
      * |col_1  |1321|10 |533.0 |634.0634826261484 |0.4334269738367066|-1.7463346405299973|
      * |col_2  |2321|20 |977.2 |1141.1895986206675|0.405051373873868 |-1.7997419516751323|
      * |col_3  |3321|30 |1421.4|1649.399072389699 |0.3979251063785061|-1.8119558312496056|
      * |col_4  |4321|40 |1865.6|2157.926620624529 |0.3950204738145622|-1.816512420634769 |
      * |col_5  |5321|50 |2309.8|2666.5902759891706|0.3935246673563024|-1.81866856281125  |
      * +-------+----+---+------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
      */
```

### you can also specify the functions as you want as below

```scala
 import RichDataframe.implicits._
 table_df.statSummary("sum", "count", "25%", "75%")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+-----+-----+---+----+
      * |columns|sum  |count|25%|75% |
      * +-------+-----+-----+---+----+
      * |col_1  |2665 |5    |100|1123|
      * |col_2  |4886 |5    |200|2123|
      * |col_3  |7107 |5    |300|3123|
      * |col_4  |9328 |5    |400|4123|
      * |col_5  |11549|5    |500|5123|
      * +-------+-----+-----+---+----+
      */
```

### Update- As per ask the new DF can be computed as below

```scala
 val count_star = table_df.count()
    table_df.statSummary("count", "approx_count_distinct", "5%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "95%",
    "max", "min", "mean", "std", "SKEWNESS", "KURTOSIS", "VARIANCE")
      .withColumn("count_star", lit(count_star))
      .selectExpr(
        "columns AS Column_Name",
        "COUNT AS number_of_values",
        "approx_count_distinct AS number_of_distinct_values",
        "approx_count_distinct AS distinct_count_with_nan",
        "(approx_count_distinct - 1) AS distinct_count_without_nan",
        "(count == approx_count_distinct) AS is_unique",
        "(count_star - count) AS number_of_missing_values",
        "((count_star - count)/count) AS percentage_of_missing_values",
        "(approx_count_distinct/count) AS percentage_of_unique_values",
        "`5%` AS 05_PCT",
        "`25%` AS 25_PCT",
        "`50%` AS 50_PCT",
        "`75%` AS 75_PCT",
        "`95%` AS 95_PCT",
        "MAX AS max",
        "MIN AS min",
        "MEAN AS mean",
        "STD AS std",
        "SKEWNESS AS skewness",
        "KURTOSIS AS kurtosis",
        "(MAX - MIN) AS range",
        "VARIANCE AS variance"
      ).show(false)

    /**
      * +-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+----+---+------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------------------+
      * |Column_Name|number_of_values|number_of_distinct_values|distinct_count_with_nan|distinct_count_without_nan|is_unique|number_of_missing_values|percentage_of_missing_values|percentage_of_unique_values|05_PCT|25_PCT|50_PCT|75_PCT|95_PCT|max |min|mean  |std               |skewness          |kurtosis           |range |variance          |
      * +-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+----+---+------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------------------+
      * |col_1      |5               |5                        |5                      |4.0                       |true     |0.0                     |0.0                         |1.0                        |10    |100   |111   |1123  |1321  |1321|10 |533.0 |634.0634826261484 |0.4334269738367066|-1.7463346405299973|1311.0|402036.5          |
      * |col_2      |5               |5                        |5                      |4.0                       |true     |0.0                     |0.0                         |1.0                        |20    |200   |222   |2123  |2321  |2321|20 |977.2 |1141.1895986206675|0.405051373873868 |-1.7997419516751323|2301.0|1302313.7000000002|
      * |col_3      |5               |5                        |5                      |4.0                       |true     |0.0                     |0.0                         |1.0                        |30    |300   |333   |3123  |3321  |3321|30 |1421.4|1649.399072389699 |0.3979251063785061|-1.8119558312496056|3291.0|2720517.3         |
      * |col_4      |5               |5                        |5                      |4.0                       |true     |0.0                     |0.0                         |1.0                        |40    |400   |444   |4123  |4321  |4321|40 |1865.6|2157.926620624529 |0.3950204738145622|-1.816512420634769 |4281.0|4656647.3         |
      * |col_5      |5               |5                        |5                      |4.0                       |true     |0.0                     |0.0                         |1.0                        |50    |500   |555   |5123  |5321  |5321|50 |2309.8|2666.5902759891706|0.3935246673563024|-1.81866856281125  |5271.0|7110703.7         |
      * +-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+----+---+------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------------------+
      */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

    val df = Seq(
      (10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
      (100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
      (10, 222, 333, 444, 555),
      (1123, 2123, 3123, 4123, 5123),
      (1321, 2321, 3321, 4321, 5321)
    ).toDF("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", "col_5")
    df.show(false)

    val descExpr = array(
      df.columns.map(c => struct(
        lit(c).cast("string").as("Column_Name"),
        count(col(c)).cast("string").as("number_of_values"),
        countDistinct(col(c)).cast("string").as("number_of_distinct_values"),
        countDistinct(col(c)).cast("string").as("distinct_count_with_nan"),
        (countDistinct(col(c)) - 1).cast("string").as("distinct_count_without_nan"),
        (count(col(c)) === countDistinct(col(c))).cast("string").as("is_unique"),
        (count("*") - count(col(c))).cast("string").as("number_of_missing_values"),
        ((count("*") - count(col(c))) / count("*")).cast("string").as("percentage_of_missing_values"),
        (countDistinct(col(c)) / count("*")).cast("string").as("percentage_of_unique_values"),
        max(col(c)).cast("string").as("max"),
        min(col(c)).cast("string").as("min"),
        mean(col(c)).cast("string").as("mean"),
        (max(col(c)) - min(col(c))).cast("string").as("range"),
        stddev(col(c)).cast("string").as("std"),
        skewness(col(c)).cast("string").as("skewness"),
        kurtosis(col(c)).cast("string").as("kurtosis"),
        variance(col(c)).cast("string").as("variance")
      )
      ): _*
    ).as("data")

    val columns = Seq("Column_Name", "number_of_values", "number_of_distinct_values", "distinct_count_with_nan", "distinct_count_without_nan", "is_unique", "number_of_missing_values", "percentage_of_missing_values", "percentage_of_unique_values", "max", "min", "mean", "range", "std", "skewness", "kurtosis", "variance")
      .map(c => if (c != "Column_Name" && c != "is_unique") col(c).cast("double").as(c) else col(c))

    var df1 = df
      .select(descExpr)
      .selectExpr("explode(data) as data")
      .select("data.*")
      .select(columns: _*)

    df1 = df1
      .withColumn("is_unique", col("is_unique").cast(BooleanType))

    val approxQuantileDF = df
      .columns
      .map(c => (c, df.stat.approxQuantile(c, Array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 0.0)))
      .toList
      .toDF("Column_Name", "approx_quantile")
      .select(
        expr("Column_Name"),
        expr("approx_quantile[0] as 05_PCT"),
        expr("approx_quantile[1] as 25_PCT"),
        expr("approx_quantile[2] as 50_PCT"),
        expr("approx_quantile[3] as 75_PCT"),
        expr("approx_quantile[4] as 95_PCT")
      )

    df1 = df1.join(approxQuantileDF, Seq("Column_Name"), "left")
    df1.show(false)
  }
```

I hope this will help. This code is just an extension to the answer provided by @Srinivas

Comment: Good...:) ..try to avoid using ```var```  & use only ```val``` where ever possible.

Comment: @Srinivas I am new to spark, can you please help me to understand small doubt? Reassigning to same ```var``` dataframe frequently will reduce my performance? I haven't seen any code with ```var``` in spark, but I also use ```var``` to define dataframes and reassign the same dataframe after transformation.

Comment: No It will not reduce any performance of your code. if you declare any variable with ```var``` it is mutable, there might be chances of getting wrong result if you use these variables in multithreads.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help.