# otherwise-clause not working as expect , whats wrong here?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v how to do various joins depend on the value of column I need get multiple look up values of map_val column for given value columns as show below.

**Sample data:**

```
val data = List(
  ("20", "score", "school", "2018-03-31", 14 , 12),
  ("21", "score", "school", "2018-03-31", 13 , 13),
  ("22", "rate", "school", "2018-03-31", 11 , 14),
  ("21", "rate", "school", "2018-03-31", 13 , 12)
 )
val df = data.toDF("id", "code", "entity", "date", "value1", "value2")

df.show

+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
| id| code|entity|      date|value1|value2|
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
| 20|score|school|2018-03-31|    14|    12|
| 21|score|school|2018-03-31|    13|    13|
| 22| rate|school|2018-03-31|    11|    14|
| 21| rate|school|2018-03-31|    13|    12|
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+




 val resultDs = df
                 .withColumn("value1",
                        when(col("code").isin("rate") , functions.callUDF("udfFunc",col("value1")))
                         .otherwise(col("value1").cast(DoubleType))
                      )
```

**udfFunc maps as follows**

```
11->a
12->b
13->c
14->d
```

**Expected output**

```
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
| id| code|entity|      date|value1|value2|
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
| 20|score|school|2018-03-31|    14|    12|
| 21|score|school|2018-03-31|    13|    13|
| 22| rate|school|2018-03-31|    a |    14|
| 21| rate|school|2018-03-31|    c |    12|
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
```

**But it is giving output as**

```
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
| id| code|entity|      date|value1|value2|
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
| 20|score|school|2018-03-31|  null|    12|
| 21|score|school|2018-03-31|  null|    13|
| 22| rate|school|2018-03-31|    a |    14|
| 21| rate|school|2018-03-31|    c |    12|
+---+-----+------+----------+------+------+
```

why "otherwise" condition is not working as expected. any idea what is wrong here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column should contains same datatype.

**Note** - `DoubleType` can not store `StringTyp` data, So you need to convert `DoubleType` to `StringType`.

```
val resultDs = df
.withColumn("value1",
        when(col("code") === lit("rate") ,functions.callUDF("udfFunc",col("value1")))
        .otherwise(col("value1").cast(StringType)) // Should be StringType
    )
```

**Or**

```
val resultDs = df
                 .withColumn("value1",
                        when(col("code").isin("rate") , functions.callUDF("udfFunc",col("value1")))
                         .otherwise(col("value1").cast(StringType)) // Modified to StringType
                      )
```

Comment: thanks a lot Srini, you been always helpful...did a overlook thanks for correcting....thanks a billion lot

Comment: can please help me on this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395767/applying-withcolumn-only-when-column-exists-in-the-dataframe

Comment: can you advice me on the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450135/applying-when-condition-only-when-column-exists-in-the-dataframe

Comment: any advice how to handle this scenario in spark ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668096/adding-a-new-column-using-withcolumn-from-a-lookup-table-dynamically

Comment: could you please advice what is wrong here in reduce function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with this broadcast variable accessing  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003697/spark-broadcast-variable-map-giving-null-value

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to modify to-

```
df
                 .withColumn("value1",
                        when(col("code") === lit("rate") , functions.callUDF("udfFunc",col("value1")))
                         .otherwise(col("value1").cast(StringType))
                      )
```

and check once

Comment: sorry no luck .. still getting  other than "rate" , value1 column coming as null.

Comment: As Srinivas explained, this is because of casting, change it to StringType

Comment: any advice how to handle this scenario in spark ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668096/adding-a-new-column-using-withcolumn-from-a-lookup-table-dynamically